# Need help related to the date and time in asp.net mvc web app

Tags: asp.net-mvc, date

I am developing on asp.net mvc, i have an issue with date time storing in sql db.

Following is my model for date field.

```
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime ReleaseDate { get; set; }
```

Following is my view for date picker

```
<div class="editor-field">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ReleaseDate, new { @class = "dpiker" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ReleaseDate)
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.dpiker').datepicker({ dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy" });
            var date = "09/12/2013";
            var parts = date.split('/');
            var date = new Date(parseInt(parts[2], 10),     // year
                                parseInt(parts[1], 10) - 1, // month, starts with 0
                                parseInt(parts[0], 10));    // day
        });
    </script>
```

This is what i do to enter date:

[image]

And this is what the output comes

[image]

So I cant figure out where do i need to parse or convert the data of the text box.

My form is serialized.

Comment: Does this help?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/206384/how-to-format-a-microsoft-json-date

Comment: _selectedReleaseDate.split('/')[0];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<p><input type="text" id="txtSelectedDate" value="@Model.ReleaseDate"</p>
    $(function () {
        $("#txtSelectedDate").datepicker({
            showButtonPanel: false
        });
    });


var _selectedReleaseDate = $('#txtSelectedDate').val();


var _selectedMonth=_selectedReleaseDate.split('/')[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it :

```
<p><input type="text" id="txtSelectedDate" value="@Model.ReleaseDate"</p>
```

//then in javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $("#txtSelectedDate").datepicker({
                showButtonPanel: false
            });
        });

//after the user selects a date you can get the value via

   var _selectedReleaseDate = $('#txtSelectedDate').val();

//then you can split like 

var _selectedMonth=_selectedReleaseDate.split('/')[0];

Hope this helps!
```

Comment: actually i have found the solution... it was even easy.... but though i am marking answer. thank you